# Hugs type signature contains extra type constraints?

Tags: haskell, hugs

Came across this while playing with Haskell and I'm stumped:

```
Hugs> :type (\x -> x^2)
\x -> x ^ 2 :: (Integral a, Num b) => b -> b
```

What is `a` doing in there? How am I supposed to read that? If I type the same thing into GHCi, it gives me the output I would expect:

```
Prelude> :type (\x -> x^2)
(\x -> x^2) :: Num a => a -> a
```

Is this a bug in Hugs?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: At least it's not Gofer :-) I imagine a lot of FP courses were written when GHC didn't have GHCi and was difficult (and large! 50MB!) to install on Windows. The whole point of Hugs was to get people to use Haskell quickly. Hugs also used to support a few interesting Haskell extensions, notably TREX. Gofer, Hugs' predecessor, was the first to introduce multi-parameter typeclasses, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Come to think of it, Gofer was Mark P. Jones' brainchild, written to experiment with fancy typeclasses like `Functor` and `Monad`. Before that (we're talking Haskell 1.3 here) typeclasses could only be declared for kinds `*`. There was a lot going on, back around 1992. On the other hand, it's still a lot of fun now: GADTs, type families and constraint kinds, oh my!

Comment: Apparently computer science professors use Hugs; I have heard that it makes a good learning platform due to its verbose error messages [citation needed].

Comment: Is this wikipedia now or something? http://xkcd.com/285/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Integral` constraint comes from the exponent of `2`. Remember that in Haskell, integer literals are actually polymorphic values of type `Num a => a`. The compiler then infers that since it's being used as an exponent to `(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`, it must be of the more constrained type `Integral a => a`.

To save you from having to disambiguate numeric literals all over your code, Haskell uses [type defaulting](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4) to pick a reasonable concrete type for any unconstrained numeric types. In this case, that will be `Integer`. The difference seems to be that `:type` in Hugs reports the inferred type before this happens, while GHCi reports the type after type defaulting has been applied.

If you specify a concrete type for the exponent yourself, the extra constraint disappears.

```
Hugs> :type (\x -> x^(2 :: Integer))
\x -> x ^ 2 :: Num a => a -> a
```

Comment: A bit strange though, as `(Integral a, Num b) => b -> b` would not be a valid type to give something explicitly, since the `a` is unused.

Comment: Very interesting. I would have expected that the program would reject it as ambiguous if it didn't type default.

Answer (score 3):

This is sort of speculation, but this might have to do with the type of `(^)`. `:t (^)` in ghci returns `(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`. I'm guessing hugs sees that the second argument of `^` needs to be an `Integral`, and even though that argument is just a constant 2, it includes the constraint in the type signature.

Comment: Yes, a deviation in hugs' printing of types from ghci's. It should probably default the 2 to Integer and only emit the base's type.